# Why does Michael Burnham not regain her insignia badge when she joins The Discovery?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-discovery, michael-burnham

In Star Trek Discovery [S1:E1](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/The_Vulcan_Hello_(episode)) - *The Vulcan Hello* - with Captain Georgiou, we see Michael Burnham wearing a Star Trek insignia badge.

[image]

Later in Star Trek Discovery [S01:E07](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Magic_to_Make_the_Sanest_Man_Go_Mad_(episode)) - *Magic to Make the Sanest Man Go Mad* we see that Michael Burnham doesn't have an insignia badge - despite having a position in the science crew.

[image]

My question is: **Why does Michael Burnham not regain her insignia badge when she joins The Discovery?**

Comment: In the latest episode, Burnham mentions that once the war ends, she goes back to jail. Her assignment on the DIscovery is a **temporary** distraction from her incarceration, she has not rejoined Starfleet.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

### Because she has no military rank

One of the purposes of the badge is to present the holder's rank. Michael Burhnam has been stripped of rank at her court-martial, therefore, although not clearly stated anywhere, she is not eligible for having a badge.

Please note that these badges are not commbadges, known from TNG+ era. Commbadges may be required to be worn by everyone (including civilians and specialists without a Starfleet rank) onboard, as they work as a communication and user-location device.  We clearly see that in ST:DIS the crew uses a TOS-era communicator devices, not the badges. We have not seen that the badges are used to locate the wearer either. Therefore, a DIS-era badge serves no practical purpose for someone without a rank.

[image]